# Filter by inner key with javascript/react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm making a page with React. I have a function that shows my all jobs, I want to write it to only give me ones that match an id.
My code in jsx:

```
                   <tbody>
                       {jobs && jobs.map(job =>
                           <tr key={job.id}>
                               <td>{job.status}</td>
                               <td>{job.fk_product}</td>
                               <td>{job.fk_order}</td>
                               <td>{job.type}</td>
                               <td>{job.fk_employee}</td>
                               <td style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       )}
                   </tbody>
```

How can I rewrite this so that it filters it by `job.fk_employee`? For example
`if(fk_employee == 5)` only then should all the values be mapped.
(map not by `job.id` but by `job.fk_employee`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it before mapping:

```
{jobs && jobs.filter(job => job.fk_employee === 5).map(job =>
  <tr key={job.id}>
    <td>{job.status}</td>
    <td>{job.fk_product}</td>
    <td>{job.fk_order}</td>
    <td>{job.type}</td>
    <td>{job.fk_employee}</td>
    <td style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
    </td>
  </tr>
)}
```

or outside the render

```
const jobsFiltered = jobs.filter(job => job.fk_employee === 5)
...
{jobsFiltered.map(job => ...)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<tbody>
  {jobs && jobs.filter(job => job.fk_employee === 5).map(job =>
  <tr key={job.id}>
    <td>{job.status}</td>
    <td>{job.fk_product}</td>
    <td>{job.fk_order}</td>
    <td>{job.type}</td>
    <td>{job.fk_employee}</td>
    <td style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
    </td>
  </tr>
  )}
</tbody>
```

also a side note if jobs is supposed to be an array it is always gonna be true so the first part of the && statement won't matter so you should probably check jobs.length

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply an inline filter function before the map. I'd relocate this up in the component but it's up to you.

```js
     <tbody>
        {jobs && jobs.filter(j => j.fk_employee === 5).map(job =>
           <tr key={job.id}>
             <td>{job.status}</td>
             <td>{job.fk_product}</td>
             <td>{job.fk_order}</td>
             <td>{job.type}</td>
             <td>{job.fk_employee}</td>
             <td style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}></td>
            </tr>
          )}
      <tbody>
```

Ideally, up in the component you should apply this filter in order to have a cleaner code.

```
filteredJobs = jobs.filter(job => job.fk_employee === id) ---> eg id = 5
```